# Nginx, PHP: Error 524, A timeout occurred (during the long working process)

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx, server

I have a Laravel project and I'm creating videos with it. And the each video creation process takes about 2-3 minutes. For some video processes I'm getting:

> Error 524  Ray ID: ... A timeout occurred

In the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file I've already added the following params

```
http {
   fastcgi_read_timeout
   fastcgi_send_timeout
   proxy_read_timeout
   proxy_send_timeout
   proxy_connect_timeout
   send_timeout
}
```

For all params I've set the unbelievable **999999** value. Also, I've updated the `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` and set them as unlimited ( `PHP version 7.2.24` ) .

After all these steps, I still have a timeout issue sometimes. What else can I do to prevent the issue?

Comment: "Ray ID" sounds like this is rather a timeout issue with Cloudflare. Please read `Quick Fix Ideas, 4.` here to find out more: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-524-a-timeout-occurred/42342
Apparently, Cloudflare is not the right choice for the way this application works.

Comment: @Damocles, thanks for your response. So, in this case I just need to use Linux hosting from Godaddy or any other hosting provider?

Comment: Or rewrite it so that the video creation is handled by a background task. For example the when the user preforms the action that creates the video instead add it to a queue (using something like RabiitMQ or a simple database table/entity), then have a scheduled task/cronjob that takes a job off the queue and creates the video. You'd then have somewhere in the UI for the user to see what jobs they have queued up, and a way to access the video when its completed.

Comment: The answer by @Technofrood is correct. Using another hosting provider might work as well if Cloudflare isn't forced on you, and the hosting provider has no (tight) limitations on PHP's `max_execution_time` - this might need some tweaking, too.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I've fixed this issue by running the video creation process in the background, using Laravel Events, Listeners and Queues